# Unity light works slowly on mobile devices

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I develop a 2D game and the problem is:

- when I add 2 simple spot lights to my scene - the performance on old
  and slow Android devices is very low (about 10-20 fps  on devices with less than 20k in antutu)
- but on new devices it's not.
- In my case I can't use baked lights because one of my spots is moving.

How to solve this issue?

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide us a screen shot of your scene?

Comment: 2d game is 2d game ) 
My background use Default Diffuse material
Screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8tsTnJ7fauRN1lYdnJTamJ6NWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should use Unlit/Transparent instead of Diffuse

Comment: Hamza Hasan, so I will give it a try.

Comment: So I didn't get it, if I use unlit/transparent the light doesn't work.

Comment: @LittleBoy as the name says "unlit-" renders in full brighness regardless of the scenes lighting.